# Can i migrate angular 1.2 app in ionic 2 framework?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I want to migrate my angular 1.2 module in ionic 2/3 frame works. Are there any chances or approached to do this? If yes, then what are the drawbacks?

Answer (score 0):

The new ionic versions use AngularJs 2+. And no those 2 are not compatible.

It probably is best if you have a look at the official upgrade migration guide from the guys at angular

https://angular.io/guide/upgrade

Are there any drawbacks? No not really. Depending on your angular 1 code and the size of the project your probably will have to refactor/recode a lot of stuff. You will see a lot of performance increase and modern code.